# Office 365 - swap subscriptions of two users

Tags: microsoft-office-365, licensing

My organization has two active Office 365 subscriptions - Business Essentials and Business Premium. I want to swap the subscription of two users - the one with Essentials to get Premium, and the one with Premium to get Essentials. I believe I did this once few years ago, but now I can't find out how and googling didn't helped me to find an answer either.

The easiest way is to increase the number of licenses for one of the subscriptions, assign the new license to one of the users, and the assigned the freed license to the other. After that I will be able to decrease the number of licenses back.

Removing the license from one of the users may destroy his mailbox, etc.

How can I swap the licenses of these 2 users, so the one with Essentials to get Premium, and the one with Premium to get the freed Essentials, without risk for data loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 30 day window after removing a license before data is removed in O365.

I've successfully pulled and swapped licenses without any issue.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/Removing-license-from-user-what-gets-removed-and-how-quickly/td-p/94141

Comment: Thank you for your response! I played safe, though. I simply increased the number of Essential licenses and used this extra one to swap the subscriptions between these two users.